# Проблема в создании модуля для Magento2

Tags: php, magento, модули

Пытаюсь сделать простой первый модуль для Magento2. Делаю все по [гайду](http://www.venustheme.com/how-to-create-magento-2-module/)

Даже все раза 4 проверил - вроде правильно все, но модуль не работает, при переходе по силке `say/index/index`,  должна открываться страница с текстом, *но результат - пустая страница бес ошибок!*

***Делаю все так:***

создаю конфиг для модуля: `app/Dev/Say/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <module name="Dev_Say" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

В корне модуля  `app/Dev/Say` создаю `registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Dev_Say',
    __DIR__
);
```

Затем делаю роутер для `frontend` `app/Dev/Say/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="say" frontName="say">
            <module name="Dev_Say"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Делаю контроллер  `app/Dev/Say/Controller/Index/index.php`

```
<?php
namespace Dev\Say\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->getLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Мой layout `app/Dev/Say/view/frontend/layout/say_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Dev\Say\Block\Say" name="lofformbuilder-toplinks" template="Dev_Say::say.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Создаю блок `app/Dev/Say/Block/Say.php`

```
<?php
namespace Dev\Say\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Say extends Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

И сам шаблон `app/Dev/Say/view/frontend/templates/say.phtml`

```
<?php
    echo 'Say template';
```

Потом регистрирую модуль и делаю `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

При открытии `say/index/index` нет никаких ошибок, просто пустая страница.

**В чем может быть моя ошибка ? Возможно я что то упустил ?**

Comment: в action die попробуй доходит вообще

Comment: @Naumov, решил проблему...Не заметил что вместо loadLayout() вызвал getLayout() в контролере !